# Combining PNG Images Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to loop through a file of png images and stitch them together to form one image. I have gotten it to work without using a for loop and just combining two images from the file. So I am assuming it is the looping that isn't working. The images are located in a file called "images".
I would appreciate your input!

```
        File file = new File("images");

    File [] moreFile = file.listFiles();
    String [] images = new String [moreFile.length];

    for(int i =0; i <images.length; i++)
        {images[i] = moreFile[i].getName();
        }

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
            controller.getSize().width*2, controller.getSize().height, //work these out
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = result.getGraphics();

    for(String image : images){
        System.out.println(image);

        File path = new File("images");
        try{ImageIO.read(new File(path, image));

        System.out.println("it definitely goes here");

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage((2*510),(2*439),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        bi =ImageIO.read(new File(path, image));

        g.drawImage(bi, x, y, null);
        g.dispose();
    /// System.out.println(dafuck);
        x += bi.getWidth();

        if(x > result.getWidth()){
            x = 0;
            y += bi.getHeight();
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("is it an exception>?");

        }
    }

    try {
        ImageIO.write(result,"png",new File("results"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How are images organized  inside `images` file?

Comment: They are not organized in any particular way. Another part of the program generates these png files and saves them in images file. And this part is trying to put them into one png.

Comment: So you mean you have each image stored in a seperate png file, then you want to group them in one single png file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Although neither of this tips will solve your problem, it will take away some of the things that might be wrong. Your code indentation is a mess. And you probably shouldn't read your image twice (the first one is just thrown away), nor should you create a `BufferedImage` in the loop (just to throw it away, as well).  However, the most important thing: What isn't working? What are the symptoms? What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: The problem is probably the `getGraphics()` before the loop, and the `g.dispose()` inside the loop. I.e. the first iteration will dispose the object, the second will crash/do nothing/other undefined behaviour. Either do both inside the loop, or move the `g.dispose()` to after the loop. I also recommend `try/finally` to avoid resource leaks, as a `Graphics` object may hold references to native OS resources.